# get function pointer of this->c1->c2->c3->myFunc();

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I'm having trouble in getting the pointer of a function that I access through pointers:

```
double *d = &(this->c1->...->myFunc();
```

does not work, `myFunc()` is declared as `double`.
Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Do you want a pointer to the function, or to its result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean that you want a pointer to the value returned by `myFunc`, then you can't: it's a temporary, and will be destroyed at the end of the expression.

If you need a pointer, then you'll also need a non-temporary value to point at:

```
double value = this->c1->...->myFunc();
double * d = &value;
```

Or are you saying that you want a pointer to the function? That's a different type to `double*`:

```
// get a member-function pointer like this
double (SomeClass::*d)() = &SomeClass::myFunc;

// call it like this
double value = (this->c1->...->*d)();
```

Or are you saying that you want something you can call like a simple function, but bound to some object `this->c1->...`? The language doesn't directly support that, but C++11 has lambdas and a `bind` function for that sort of thing:

```
// Bind a function to some arguments like this
auto d = std::bind(&SomeClass::myFunc, this->c1->...);

// Or use a lambda to capture the object to call the member function on
auto d = [](){return this->c1->...->myFunc();};

// call it like this
double value = d();
```

Comment: Thank you for your Help!In the first case i get an error : & expects L value...(translated from german) 
what I try to do is to have a pointer to the function

Comment: @user1679802: Sorry, I made a copy/paste error. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that in `this->c1->c2->c3->myFunc()` c3 is of type `foo`:

```
class foo 
{
public:
  double myFunc();
};
```

Then you can say:

```
typedef double (foo::*pmyfunc)(void);
```

And then take its address:

```
pmyfunc addr = &foo::myFunc;
```

You should read the [Pointers to member](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html) functions FAQs.